# Bitnami Keycloak with external database (AWS RDS)

Tags: keycloak, amazon-rds, bitnami

I'm trying to setup Keycloak using helm and bitnami/keycloak chart using an external database (AWS RDS).

Here's my config:

```
proxy: edge
replicaCount: 2
resources:
  requests:
    memory: "512Mi"
    cpu: "500m"
  limits:
    memory: "1024Mi"
    cpu: "1000m"

postgresql:
  enabled: false

externalDatabase:
  database: keycloak
  host: jdbc:postgresql://{aws-instance}.{aws-region}.rds.amazonaws.com
  user: {user}
  password: {password}

cache:
  enabled: true

ingress:
  enabled: true
  hostname: auth.identione.com
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: {certificateArn}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: '443'

autoscaling:
  enabled: true
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 5
```

But i get the following error message on my pods when installing the chart.

```
cannot resolve host "jdbc:postgresql://{aws-instance}.{aws-region}.rds.amazonaws.com": lookup jdbc:postgresql://{aws-instance}.{aws-region}.rds.amazonaws.com.rds.amazonaws.com: no such host
```

The documentation on external database setup is pretty slim...

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.

the `host` variable aren't supposed to include `jdbc:postgresql://`